# SVG rendering in Microsoft Edge

Tags: svg, microsoft-edge

I'm using `<svg>` tags using the `<use>` node to duplicate images within my html page. But these are not rendering in Microsoft Edge. Is there a workaround?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet? I've just tried recreating the issue in this JSBin sample, but I'm able to repeat the image elements. http://jsbin.com/cazasi/edit?html,output

Comment: I use something in the lines of

Comment: I use something in the lines of
`<svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="images/svg/svgname.svg#icon-id"></use>
</svg>`


And the svg file has multiple images differentiated by 
`<symbol id="icon-id">` 

and following is the path.

Like `<symbol id="icon-id">
             <path ...../>
        </symbol>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use something like svg4everybody to get this to work. Older versions of the script didn't have the right UA string, but the latest version should correctly target Edge now.

Noticed this myself after upgrading to Windows 10 and updating the script fixed it. IE 9-11 worked fine before the update but not Edge as the UA wasn't included in the check.  The npm version was also just updated so you can grab it from there as well.

Comment: If I don't get it wrong, svg4everybody uses png images for fallbacks, doesn't it? So I will lost all the svg styling possibilities?

Comment: You can use the fallback for < IE9 to use png files you generate yourself I believe. You won't be able to style them, but it would still probably be better than displaying nothing at all.

Comment: I would recommend using svgxuse instead of svg4everybody: https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse